# MYSQL: Need help creating a stock depletion report

Tags: mysql, inventory, stock

I need advice on how I go about creating a report that will show a list of products in first column and the subsequent columns will be time periods.

The Stock table has the following fields:

Stock_ID
StockQty
InStock_Date
UsageRate

What I'm looking to do is to look at each Stock Item and by using its Usage Rate slot a value into future time periods.

For example if ProductA is currently in stock, has a stock qty of 100 and a usage rate of 10 per week then I would need to populate the report with the next 10 Weeks with a quantity of 10.
ProductB may have an in-stock quantity of 30 and a usage rate of 4/week so I need to populate the next row of table with the next 7 weeks with value of 4 and Week 8 with the remainder of the stock, 2.  And so on with the remaining products.

A further requirement is handling Products that come into in the future for example 5 weeks from now. I would like to perform the above but the starting Week will be Week 5.

Another thing I would like to do is to perform calculations on the above such as multiplying each weeks quantities by the products' selling prices to get projected income by week.

I'm using MYSQL 5, and tried the following solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_DBR_Inventory_Test() 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE i INT Default 0; 
    declare Max_Period_Id int(3) default 0; 
    select max(ceiling(Stock_QTY/Stock_Usage)) 
      from hilmark.stock 
      into Max_Period_Id; 

    simple_loop: 
      LOOP SET i=i+1; 
      select Stock_Id, 
             Stock_Usage 
        from hilmark.stock; 
      IF i=Max_Period_Id THEN LEAVE simple_loop; END IF; 
    END LOOP simple_loop; 
  END
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Cheers

Jake

Comment: Could you please post code samples of what you have tried so far

Comment: I've been trying the following:CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_DBR_Inventory_Test`()
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT Default 0;
declare Max_Period_Id int(3) default 0;

select max(ceiling(Stock_QTY/Stock_Usage)) from hilmark.stock into Max_Period_Id;

         simple_loop: LOOP
         SET i=i+1;

         select Stock_Id, 
         
                 
         Stock_Usage from hilmark.stock;
         
         
         IF i=Max_Period_Id THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;

END
$$ I

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the above by creating a temporary table and reporting of that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_DBR_Inventory_Test`()
```

BEGIN

DECLARE i INT Default 0; 
    declare Max_Period_Id int(3) default 0;

```
select max(ceiling(Stock_QTY/Stock_Usage)) 
  from hilmark.stock 
  into Max_Period_Id;
```

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE salestimeline_tmp (
    Stock_ID int(4),Period_ID int(2),Sales_Qty int(3));

```
simple_loop: LOOP 

SET i=i+1; 

 insert into salestimeline_tmp 

    select a.Stock_Id,
        i,
        case
        when a.Stock_Usage*i >= a.Stock_Qty
         then
            case
            when (a.Stock_Usage*i-a.Stock_Qty) < a.Stock_Usage then (a.Stock_Qty-a.Stock_Usage*(i-1))
            else
            0
            end 
        else 
        a.Stock_Usage
        end as SUsage

    from hilmark.stock a;

  IF i=Max_Period_Id THEN LEAVE simple_loop; 

  END IF; 

END LOOP simple_loop;
```

select * from salestimeline_tmp;

END
$$